# How to compare rows in to separate spreadsheets using SpreadSheetLight and return differences

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, openxml

I'm a bit new to C# / ASP.NET - I have 2 excel spreadsheets

*sheet1* has 3 columns with values. 
*sheet2* has 2 columns with valuse.

I'm trying to compare row data in them both. It's working but I'm not sure how to catch if the data in *sheet1* is not the same in *sheet2*?

**Any help to what I am missing would be appreciated.**

```
StringBuilder compErroWorkSheet = new StringBuilder();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var firstdoc = new SLDocument(@"C:\boarding Files for testing\Sample Offboarding Work Area\Kim.Jay\SpreadsheetsFromDC\test.xlsx", "Sheet2");

    var secondoc = new SLDocument(@"C:\boarding Files for testing\Sample Offboarding Work Area\Kim.Jay\ValidatedCSVs\Test1.xlsx", "Sheet2");


    AreSheetsIdentical(firstdoc, secondoc);

    // Error file for Document Services person
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "text";

    //TODO: Also save in a safe place first
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=errors.csv");
    Response.Write(compErroWorkSheet.ToString());
    Response.End();
} 

private bool AreSheetsIdentical(SLDocument firstdoc, SLDocument secondoc)
{
    SLWorksheetStatistics stats1 = firstdoc.GetWorksheetStatistics();
    SLWorksheetStatistics stats2 = secondoc.GetWorksheetStatistics();


    for (int j = 1; j < stats1.EndRowIndex; j++)
    {
        if (firstdoc.GetCellValueAsString(0, j) != secondoc.GetCellValueAsString(0, j))
            return false;

        compErroWorkSheet.AppendLine("Errors");
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I fixed it....  however I'm still need to write the differences to a NEW csv file or spreadsheet.

private bool AreSheetsIdentical(SLDocument firstdoc, SLDocument secondoc)
        {
            SLWorksheetStatistics stats1 = firstdoc.GetWorksheetStatistics();
            SLWorksheetStatistics stats2 = secondoc.GetWorksheetStatistics();


            for (int j = 1; j
```